# fiddler autoresponder works with https in Chrome browser

Tags: fiddler

How can I get Fiddler autoresponder works with https link?

I tried adding this rule:

```
EXACT: https://mysite/_layout/351/test.js
C:\Users\john\Desktop\test\test.js
```

But when I load https://mysite/_layout/351/test.js in my browser chrome, I don't see my C:\Users\john\Desktop\test\test.js, I see the original content from mysite. But if I do the same in IE, the rule works (i.e. I see my verion of test.js).

Do you know why fiddler autoresponder does not work with Chrome but with IE?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issue, this worked for me:
[image: screen]

Comment: I also had to restart Fiddler after making this change.